# Share passwords between users in a secure way in a Windows Forms application with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, winforms, security

There are tons of articles explaining how to safely store a user's password using hashing with salt: this is good for authentication, but not for password storage.

I want my users to be able to save credentials for websites and services in our software and let them share this credentials with colleagues. This can't be done with hashing, obviously, or using their Windows authentication as key, since the encrypted value would not be decrypted by other users.

What is my best option?

Edit: forgot to mention that users are authenticated to our software using their Windows Identity

Comment: "I want my users to be able to save credentials for websites and services in our software and let them share this credentials with colleagues" - say what? Sounds like a very bad idea and very poor design. Can you explain a bit more? Perhaps you have an XY problem?

Comment: If you're storing the passwords, and then want to share them elsewhere, that means that you want to store them in a way that they can be unencrypted; by users. This is rarely a good idea. If you want to store, and share passwords, why not use a password application that already exists?

Comment: I may have a XY problem @MitchWheat, here's the thing: I have users of our backoffice system that write passwords on text files on their desktop and share them via email. They need to share these passwords, this is by design. I want to give them a more proper way keep organized and share these credentials. I personally use LastPass but using third party external services is not possible. My first tought is to add this functionality to the backoffice software they already use.

Comment: More than one person needs to access external services we use and we can only have one account on those services. It's outside our control: account is per-company.

Comment: Then use an off-the-shelf 'Password safe'

Comment: Ok, the question is now "How an off-the-shelf 'Password safe' stores passwords"?

Comment: What's the key then? A password? A certificate?